# How to run a Cron job for every 5 mins for only 30 mins?

Tags: linux, cron

I want to run a Cron job for every 5 mins for 30 mins, starting at 22:30 till 23:00.

To do this I wrote it like this

`0 30,0/5 22 ? * * *`

If you put this in https://crontab.cronhub.io/

It will say:

> At 30 minutes past the hour and every 5 minutes, starting every hour, between 10:00 PM and 10:59 PM

But when I looked at the logs, I see it started the run at 22:00 till 22:55.

Why is this happening? Also, how can I make it work like the way I want it to.

Comment: I think I found the solution after thinking again. `0 30/5 22 ? * * *` will serve the purpose.

Comment: From the cron tag: Questions about configuring cron for systems or administration are OFF TOPIC.